# Excel: if, countif & vlookup combination

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, countif

I have two lists of data.

List A contains names: 'Name'

List B contains names and addresses: 'Name', 'address 1', 'address 2', 'city', 'county', 'postcode', 'country'.

I want to look-up the names from List A and automatically pull across the address data from List B if the names match exactly.

I tried: =if(countif('LIST B'!A:G,'LIST A'A2,"TRUE"),vlookup('LIST A'A2,'LIST B'!A:A,2,'LIST B'!A:A,""),)

But it doesn't work...

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ListB is on its own tab, similar to the following

[image]

The following would return the Address1 for the name in A2

```
=INDEX(ListB!B:B,MATCH(A2,ListB!A:A,0))
```

You can repeat the lookups for the other columns and catenate the strings, and add error checking when there is no match.